# Functions discrete maths, not understanding the question, need an explanation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

For each of the following functions, determine whether it is one-to-one and/or onto, and brieﬂy explain your answer. If the function is not onto, describe its range. 
(a) succ : N → N, where succ(n) = n + 1. 
(b) + : N×N → N, where +(n,m) = n + m.

I am struggling to understand how this works, could someone please explain?

Comment: (a) Is it one-to-one? (if $n+1 = m+1$ then does $n = m$?) is it onto? (is every nonnegative integer the successor of another nonnegative integer? No? OK, which ones are $succ(n)$ for some $n\ge 0$? That's the range.

Comment: It seems that half the world includes 0 in N and half don't. Which N are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One to one, or injective, is defined as follows.

$\phi : A \rightarrow B$ is *one-to-one*, or **injective**, if $\phi (m) = \phi (n)$ implies $m = n$ for all $m,n \in A$.

Onto, or surjective, is defined as follows.

$\phi : A \rightarrow B$ is *onto*, or **surjective**, if for every $y \in B$ there exists $x \in A$ such that $\phi(x) = y$.

$\,$

Now consider part $(a)$. Let the successor function be given by $\phi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $succ(n) = \phi(n) = n + 1$.

Is $\phi$ injective? If $\phi (m) = \phi (n)$ with $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ is it always true that $m = n$?.

By the definition of the successor map, $\phi (m) = \phi (n)$ implies $m + 1 = n + 1$. Assuming you have the cancellation law of $1$ in $\mathbb{N}$ then $m = n$ so $\phi$ is injective, or one-to-one.

Is $\phi$ surjective? In other words, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ does there exist $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi (m) = n$? Consider $n = 1$. Is there an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi (m) = m + 1 = 1$? You may think $m = 0$ will work, but $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $\phi$ is not surjective, or onto.

Now see if you can use this same logic for part $(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, for a function f: A -> B to be surjective, every element of B must have a preimage in A, or for all b in B, there exists an a in A such that f(a)=b.
For a function f: A -> B to be injective, the preimage of every element of B is unique (if it has one), or for a,c in A, f(a)=f(c) implies that a=c.

The questions you should be asking yourself here for (a) should be whether every natural number is equal to another natural number + 1 for surjectivity, and whether for natural numbers n and m, if n+1=m+1, does n=m for injectivity.

The range describes the set of all elements in the codomain, or target set of the function, that have a preimage. In other words, for f: A -> B, the range is the set of all b in B where there exists an a in A such that f(a)=b.